# Showing/ hiding a div when click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show and hide a div when clicking a link. I got the div to show correctly, but I want that div to go away when I click a different one. This is the code I currently have.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                $('#attach_silver').click(function() {
                    $('#sec_silver').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });

            $(function() {
                $('#attach_gold').click(function() {
                    $('#sec_gold').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });

            $(function() {
                $('#attach_platinum').click(function() {
                    $('#sec_platinum').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });
        </script>

<a href="#" id="attach_silver">Silver</a>
    <a href="#" id="attach_gold">Gold</a>
    <a href="#" id="attach_platinum">Platinum</a>

<div id="sec_silver" style="display: none;">
        Hello world!! Silver              
    </div>

    <div id="sec_gold" style="display: none;">
        Hello world!! Gold             
    </div>

    <div id="sec_platinum" style="display: none;">
        Hello world!! Platinum            
    </div>
```

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing just that? Also, you really don't need three `document.ready` event handlers, you only need one and to put all the code that runs on `document.ready` inside that one event handler.

Answer (score 2):

try to add a class

```
<div id="sec_silver" style="display: none;" class="divclass">
    Hello world!! Silver              
</div>

<div id="sec_gold" style="display: none;" class="divclass">
    Hello world!! Gold             
</div>

<div id="sec_platinum" style="display: none;" class="divclass">
    Hello world!! Platinum            
</div>
```

and after this code in jquery

```
       $(function() {
                $('#attach_silver').click(function() {
                    $('.divclass').hide();
                    $('#sec_silver').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });

            $(function() {
                $('#attach_gold').click(function() {
                    $('.divclass').hide();
                    $('#sec_gold').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });

            $(function() {
                $('#attach_platinum').click(function() {
                    $('.divclass').hide();
                    $('#sec_platinum').show();
                    return false;
                });        
            });
```

In this mode you hide all div on a click event, and show the div that you want

Answer (score 1):

Your click events currently show the relevant div, you just need them to hide the other divs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**^ attribute-starts with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('div[id^="sec_"]').hide(); // will hide all the div with id starting with sec_
```

your code becomes

```
$(function () {
    $('#attach_silver').click(function () {
        $('div[id^="sec_"]').hide();// add here
        $('#sec_silver').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('#attach_gold').click(function () {
        $('div[id^="sec_"]').hide();// add here
        $('#sec_gold').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('#attach_platinum').click(function () {
        $('div[id^="sec_"]').hide();// add here
        $('#sec_platinum').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only show the other divs, you never tell them to hide:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $('#attach_silver').click(function () {
        console.log('sliver click');
        $('#sec_silver').show();
        $('#sec_gold').hide();
        $('#sec_platinum').hide();
        return false;
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#attach_gold').click(function () {
        $('#sec_gold').show();
        $('#sec_silver').hide();
        $('#sec_platinum').hide();
        return false;
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#attach_platinum').click(function () {
        $('#sec_platinum').show();
        $('#sec_gold').hide();
        $('#sec_silver').hide();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How about a two line solution**

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('div:contains('+$(this).text()+')').show();
    $('div:not(:contains('+$(this).text()+'))').hide();
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x53VJ/17/)

Answer (score 0):

I like the id/class pattern. Also, by adding a class you can remove that inline style. Add:

```
.divclass{
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with javascript:

`<a href="#xyz" onclick="hideDiv();">Hide Div</a>`

```
function hideDiv()
{
 document.getElementById('myContainerDiv').style.display = "none";
}
```